# How can this final member in a Java class be null?

Tags: java

Sorry, new to Java.

I have a code like this:

```
    public class abc implements xyz {



    private final static ABCParameters defaultAbcParameters = ABCParameters.newBuilder()
            ....
            ....
            .build();

    ...
    ...
    
    }
```

ABCParameters is a google protobuf message, and we have the generated JAVA code for that.

1. Is there any possibility for defaultAbcParameters to be null? Wouldn't this be initialized when the class gets loaded?
2. How is this way of initialization different from initializing in the constructor?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What if `build()` returned `null`? Also what if this threw an exception? As for "How is this way of initialization different from initializing in the constructor?" - well, since this field is static you can't initialize it in a constructor. Aside from that, e.g. if it wasn't static, a key difference is execution order.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, if the builder returns null.
2. The difference is that your variable is static so it is shared by all the instances of the abc class. If you would initialise in the constructor, then the variable wouldn't be static anymore and it would be one per class instance.